# How do I set the default 'save-as' name for an image generated in PHP?

Tags: php, header

this is my code.

```
<?php
function generate_card($card_number='',$card_price='',$card_expire='',$image_path='',$font_path)
{
    // store image on variable //
    $image = imagecreatefrompng($image_path);

    // some text color
    $color = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 0);

    // print card price //
    imagettftext($image, 15, 0, 200, 40, $color, $font_path, $card_price);
    // print card number //
    imagettftext($image, 15, 0, 15, 85, $color, $font_path, $card_number);
    // print expiry date //
    imagettftext($image, 12, 0, 145, 155, $color, $font_path, $card_expire);

    header('Content-type:image/png');
    imagepng($image);
    imagedestroy($image); 
}
generate_card('1234 5678 9101 1121','$200','12/13','card.png','verdana.ttf');
?>
```

I am generating visa gift cards, image also created and displayed on the page. But my problem is when i want to save this image in Mozilla it gives the "page_name.png" and in IE it gives me "Untitled".
How can i give my own name like "visa_gift_01.png" while saving.

Comment: please edit your question to show code formatting.

Comment: I formatted the code for you. In future you can format code by putting 4 spaces at the beginning of the line (the button with 0s and 1s on it will do this for you automatically).

Answer (score 6):

Read this [document](http://www.jonasjohn.de/snippets/php/headers.htm)
It explain how to modify a http header

```
header('Content-Disposition:attachment;filename="visa_gift_01.png"');
```

Answer (score 5):

You can send an additional HTTP [header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) to set the download name:

```
// Change the download name to visa_gift_01.png
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="visa_gift_01.png"');
```

Comment: you are right veger if i want to download the image ... i am not telling that ... i am displaying 20 cards per page. when i "right clicked" on the image and click "save as" then it has to give the name.

Comment: @Madan Sapkota this also works when you add the images to the HTML document with `<img>` tags. At least it does for me...

Comment: @Veger -> i am not adding in any <img /> tag. i am looping the functions and getting the cards. suppose i want to display 20 images then i will loop 20 times this function. from 20 images i can select any and "right click" and "save as" that time it's giving "page_name.png" or "Untitled" i want my own here.

Comment: How do you display them (in order to "right click" on them), show them in a HTML page? Did you actually try to add the additional header?

Comment: @Veger: I don't think this guy actually knows what we are talking about. We can't help him, here. It just doesn't make any sense!?!

Comment: Care to tell what the problem was? It might help others with the same problem who find your question!

Comment: @Veger & @aefxx -> first you have to accept that you don't know more then this. definitely you will stop help if you don't know. but don't stop other ... all the world will not be like you. thank you for all. i solved the problem.

Comment: I am stopping no-one. I am just curious what the problem was and how you solved it. So *I* can learn something from it.

Answer (score 3):

In order to display the image in the browser, but still provide a filename for when the user right clicks it and chooses "Save as...", here's what you want:

```
header('Content-Disposition: Inline; filename="'.$filename.'"');
```

Using `Inline` instead of `Attachment` is the key difference from the other answers, which will cause the image to be downloaded instead of displayed in the browser when loading the page.

Comment: Nice hack!! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What you need to add is another header:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$name.'"');
```

Should be sufficient.

Comment: you are right aefxx if i want to download the image ... i am not telling that ... i am displaying 20 cards per page. when i "right clicked" on the image and click "save as" then it has to give the name.

Comment: Are you embeding the images in an HTML page or just links to the PHP file that creates the images on the fly?

Comment: i will get price,expiry date and card number from database and on the fly i will call this function passing different params then the card will display on the page. When i "right clicked" randomly on any image is has to save as "gift_card_" . $x . where $x is something different for every card.

Comment: That's not what I'm asking for. I wanted to know how the user is supposed to arrive at the site showing the images. Are you using <img/> tags or is he following a link to the dynamic image creation (your PHP code)?

Comment: when i reach "user_card.php" then user can see the cards available to purchase. so in that page i am collecting the cards available with me and calling this function in loop. suppose 5 cards i want to sell then i will call this function 5 times.